Is parallelism really useful for memory-hard key derivation functions?
Argon2 has a parallolism parameter, that basically works like this:

In a given pass, threads work alone, independent of other threads. Within this pass, there isn't much memory-hardness, as each thread's memory could be run in a separate machine with smaller memory than the total memory.
After a given pass, the threads talk to each other, which is how they become dependent on each other.

Is this really useful?  Or is it more harmful?  If we have a single thread, then every iteration will be fully dependent on every requested memory.
In other words, increasing parallelism reduces memory-hardness. Our security here is really based on memory-hardness, not based on parallelism.  We're big losers on parallelism, as ASICs can massively beat us.
So why are we giving up memory-hardness (our strength) to buy parallelism (our weakness)?

To give an example: say that I have 4GB that I want to use for memory hardness. I have two options:

Have a single thread that pounds those 4GBs with maximum memory hardness. It'd take longer to finish pounding them, but memory hardnesss is maximum.
Here, at every point, any of the 4GBs could depend on any operation. So an attacker would have a tough time guessing which memory block to free/optimise out, as he would really have to have 4GBs in each of his ASICs all the time.

Have 4 threads to pound those 4GBs with reduced memory hardness. The programme will finish faster, but with reduced memory hardness.
Here, the threads will work in batches.  Each thread's batch size is XB bytes where they perform the write operation.  They read from the rest of the 4GB - 4 * XB bytes.  Here, while the threads are working, memory hardness is only on 4GB - 4 * XB bytes.
Reducing XB to increase the memory hardness will increase thread synchronisation overhead, which is a loss.  So, usually, XB has to be large enough, but not too large.  This is a bit ambiguous to me.


How to tell if XB is worth it?  Or how to tell if parallelism is not worth it at all?

To me parallelism was always to decrease the time for the user to wait for the password based KDF to finish while keeping the same amount of ops, or to increase the number of ops for the same waiting time. And yes, we'd assume massively parallel machines for breaking rather than superfast single thread. And if required it is still possible to use time-division multithreading, i.e. running multiple threads on a single core.

But is it more secure to finish faster?  Using 4 threads over 4GB memory would finish 4 times faster. But how much of security would it reduce against a massively parallelised machine?

There's another POV here. A defender is only willing to spend so much time on computing the hard function. If parallelism lets them compute the function faster, that helps reduce the advantage of the attacker relative to the defender. For example, the defender may not be able to tolerate computing argon over 4GB on a single core. However, by using 4 cores the effective time required is equivalent to the 1GB single core case. This buys a performance improvement that can then be reinvested into making the function harder(ie 4 core 8GB or 4 core 4GB+increased iteration count).

Put it another way, parallelism increases the usage of the defender's computational resources. For example, many machines can run 4 separate threads simultaneously. Using only 1 thread basically wastes the computational power of the other 3 potentially usable threads. So long as the function is designed properly, this also increases the amount of resources an attacker needs to compute the function as well.

PS for Argon2(all variants), my tuning recommendations is as follows:
1- Start from baseline recommended values.
2- Increase parallelism first until it triggers a slow down.
3- Increase memory consumption until you hit a limit
4- Increase iteration count until you hit a limit

@oaky_0ffc—with Argon2, I think, it depends on the width of the "working area".  I think for 4GB total size, the 4 threads might be something like 400MB in parallel; I.e. 3.6GB memory hardness for 4-times speed up.  I.e. runtime reduced by 75%, while memory hardness is reduced by 10% in terms of total size.  Performance speed up is clearly linear as we increase parallelism, but is security reduction also linear as we decrease memory hardness? Or is it exponential? Security reduction is the increase in total calculations should the adversary repeat if he reduced his memory by 10%.

Decrease memory hardness compared to what? If you're worried about the amount of memory (4 GiB is a lot, it is definitely outside what a ASIC can use within the algorithm implementation) then maybe yes. Normally we however first look at the number of ops. In that sense there is no security reduction at all when using parallelism and possibly an increase if a higher number of ops can be selected for the same user experience. That all said, if you're really worried and operate using a lot of memory then keeping the number of threads to 1 does make sense.

Same goes if you have got a number of concurrent users during authentication that is is higher than the number of cores used, as otherwise they'll be waiting on each other. In your situation however I would mainly optimize for the amount of memory that is actually used, because that is a much bigger limitation (cache misses are definitely a thing here).

There are a few problems with parallelism. Different devices have a different number of cores, and an incorrect parallelism can cause denial of service or give the attacker an advantage. Supporting parallelism also complicates a design. Argon2's design is significantly more complicated due to their approach to parallelism compared to scrypt/Balloon. That's why it's easier to always set p=1 or not support parallelism. The bigger issue here is that password hashing has received minimal study compared to various other areas. Argon2 is far from optimal, and yet we've almost given up.

@samuel-lucas6 Why do you think that people have given up?

@MaartenBodewes Right… However, I'm asking about if reduction in space is even worth it security wise.  You know, this mem-hardness aims to punish whomever wants to run it with less memory, and I'm not sure but I guess the punishment is exponential increase in computation. If true, I wonder if it's wise even if we don't care about users time.

I cannot answer "is it worth it"-questions, that's subjective. I'd avoid parallelism if the PBKDF can run with a high work factor while the user doesn't experience significant slowdown. What's significant is of course also subjective and it will be bound to a specific situation.

@caveman Because there are barely any papers on password hashing from what I've seen. The PHC happened and since then the major schemes have been Balloon, Pufferfish2, and bscrypt, except none of them have proper specifications and only one has a paper. Only a handful of cryptographers seem to write papers on password hashing. Then lots of people are recommending Argon2 either because it's basically the best we have or because they're unaware of its shortcomings. People are aware that bcrypt can be better than Argon2 at short runtimes but nothing is being done with this info besides bscrypt.

@samuel-lucas6 But why aren't cryptographers interested in this subject?

@caveman I'm not sure. Could be a lack of interest, lack of knowledge, lack of equipment (GPUs/ASICs/FPGAs), or a focus on other problems like PQC. Cryptographers often seem to favour symmetric or asymmetric topics and then might focus on one specific area like AEADs. Most probably don't have experience with password cracking. That rules out lots of people. There are also efforts to get rid of passwords/use PAKEs. Then it perhaps doesn't lend itself to proofs very well, which a lot of academics seem to take very seriously. ~15 years of bcrypt/PBKDF2 until the PHC started (now 10 years ago).
